# Javascript disable inversed scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built a page that has full height inline-block links containing imagery  - the divs scroll off the page horizontally - heres is the html -

```
 <section class="banner-cont">


                <a class="banner-block bnr-lad" href="#animatedLadies"><div class="txt"><h3>Ladies Day <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span></h3></div><div class="trapper bn1"></div></a>
                <a class="banner-block bnr-g "><div class="txt"><h3>Grand Floral <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span></h3></div><div class="trapper bn2"></div></a>
                <a class="banner-block bnr-gala animatedModalGala"><div class="txt"><h3>Gala Evening<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit </span></h3></div><div class="trapper bn3"></div></a>

                <div class="banner-block "><div class="txt"><h3>Show Gardens<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span></h3></div><div class="trapper bn5"></div></div>
                <div class="banner-block "><div class="txt"><h3>Food <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span></h3></div><div class="trapper bn6"></div></div>
                <div class="banner-block "><div class="txt"><h3>Entertainment <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit </span></h3></div><div class="trapper bn7"></div></div>

              </section>
```

I use the following script to invert the mouse scroll to scroll through the off page imagery:

```
$("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);

      event.preventDefault();

   });
```

All works nicely until the client wanted to add a modal when clicking on each div block - the issue i have is that i then need to turn off teh inverted scroll whilst themodal is present and re-establish it once the modal is closed - but i dont know how to reverse the above mousewheel javascript - can anyone offer any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is to use delegate event handling,  those won't work with `scroll` but with `mousewheel`, and tell that the event callback should not be called if `html` has the class `modal-opened`. And then add the class `modal-opened` when the dialog is opened. Maybe there is already a class added to `html` when the modal is opened, then you could reuse that class.

```js
$(document).on('mousewheel', 'html:not(.modal-opened) body', function(event, delta) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('ok: ' + delta);
});


$(document).on('click', '.toggle-modal', function() {
  $('html').toggleClass('modal-opened');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>

<button class="toggle-modal">
  toggel modal-open
</button>
```

Another way would be to use a namespace to register the event listener

```
$(document).on('mousewheel.inverse-scrolling', function(event, delta) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('ok: ' + delta);
});
```

And remove the `mousewheel` event listener using the `off` function:

```
$(document).off('mousewheel.inverse-scrolling')
```

and later add the event listener again as soon as the modal closed.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `if` to your event listener to check if the modal is open. If so, do nothing. If not, then run the code.

Answer (score 1):

Store the scroll value in a variable

```
var storedScroll = null;    
$("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
storedScroll = this.scrollLeft;
storedScroll -= (delta * 30);
}
```

then use storedScroll value to scroll to the original position.

Hope that help.